# Update og:title

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

i used this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ to make my first App but i want to use php variable for my og:title like this `<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />` . This php variable is changing constantly every time the page loads but when I post my action in the facebook appears with the old title!

Here's the code:

```
      <?php
    $title = ' Hello world';
 // <---- This php variable is changing every time 
the page loads but the title is not being recognised

    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
    xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# fitnessgod: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/fitnessgod#">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="My app Id" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="fitnessgod:news" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.fitness-god.com/share-facebook.php" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="let's do sport" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.fitness-god.com/images/sport dinamic.png" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function postCook()
    {
    FB.api('/me/fitnessgod:share' + 
    '?news=https://www.fitness-god.com/share-facebook.php','post',
    function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
    } else {
    alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
    }
    });
    }
    </script>
    </head> 

<body> 

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

    <script>

    FB.init({ 

    appId:'My App id', cookie:true, 

    status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true

    });

    </script>

<fb:add-to-timeline></fb:add-to-timeline>

<h3>

    <font size="30" face="verdana" color="grey">

    Stuffed Cookies

    </font> 

    </h3> 

    <p>

    <img title="Sports News" 

    src="https://www.fitness-god.com/images/sport dinamic.png" 

    width="550"/><br />

    </p> 

 <form>

    <input type="button" value="Share news" onClick="postCook()" /> 

    </form>
    <fb:activity actions="fitnessgod:share"></fb:activity>
    </body> 

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the meta tags definition. Use attribute name, not property:

E.g.:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
```

You can use the debugger to test your code:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also note that when you click share, the content of your page might be cached. But, the debugger, always gets the latest content.

Comment: Thank's for your quick reply! Can you please test this because this is the way i want my page to work:

Comment: Thank's for quick reply ! can you test this link's please because this is the way i want to use my api: For test try to share this an see if the title is changing:
test1: https://www.fitness-god.com/share-facebook.php?id=20
test2: https://www.fitness-god.com/share-facebook.php?id=21
test3: with id=22 Everytime my title should be recognised !

Comment: if id=20; title= Hello world; if id=21; title=  Hello there; if id=21; title= Hello you;

Comment: you need to change `<meta property="...">` with `<meta name="...">`. The attribute should be `name`, NOT `property`. See the answer above

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are experiencing "freezing" of `og:title` that Facebook performs after a number of actions – 50 likes, shares and/or comments – were performed with that link.

One of the main reasons why Facebook does this, is to prevent many people sharing a seemingly safe link and then having the site owner replace the title with offensive content and have it display on people's timelines.

For additional information, see [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/faq#faq_1535561513411673).